# Get the index of div that has not a common class Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I just wanted to get the index of the div that doesn't have class "already" this is my code.

```
 $('#slotMachine #slotMachine2 div.combi:not(.already):first').index();
```

This is my html code.

```
<li id="slotMachine2">
<div class="combi already" data-id="17">JOHN4654</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="18">JOHN4015</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="19">JOHN1235</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="20">JOHN0454</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="21">JOHN1254</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="22">JOHN0014</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="23">JOHN1387</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="24">JOHN2478</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="25">JOHN8475</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="26">JOHN3597</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="27">JOHN7985</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="28">JOHN3154</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="29">JOHN9001</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="30">JOHN0034</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="31">JOHN0215</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="32">JOHN3795</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="33">JOHN1567</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="34">JOHN6523</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="35">JOHN7956</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="36">JOHN1547</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="37">JOHN6872</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="38">JOHN3487</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="39">JOHN8392</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="40">JOHN3432</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="41">JOHN3412</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="42">JOHN3413</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="43">JOHN3419</div>
<div class="combi already" data-id="44">JOHN3423</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="45">JOHN3429</div>
<div class="combi" data-id="46">JOHN3427</div></li>
```

The result I always get is zero. Thank you in advance masters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify based on which collection you need to get index.

```js
// cache the selector and based on this get index
var $col = $('#slotMachine #slotMachine2 div.combi');

console.log(
  // get the element within the collection to find index
  // and set it as `index()` methods argument
  $col.index($col.filter(':not(.already):first'))
);

// your code also works if there is siblings as in your html
console.log(
  $('#slotMachine #slotMachine2 div.combi:not(.already):first').index()
)


// or you can set the selector in which look for an element
console.log(
  $('#slotMachine #slotMachine2 div.combi:not(.already):first').index('#slotMachine #slotMachine2 div.combi')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slotMachine">
  <li id="slotMachine2">
    <div class="combi already" data-id="17">JOHN4654</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="18">JOHN4015</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="19">JOHN1235</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="20">JOHN0454</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="21">JOHN1254</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="22">JOHN0014</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="23">JOHN1387</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="24">JOHN2478</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="25">JOHN8475</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="26">JOHN3597</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="27">JOHN7985</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="28">JOHN3154</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="29">JOHN9001</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="30">JOHN0034</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="31">JOHN0215</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="32">JOHN3795</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="33">JOHN1567</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="34">JOHN6523</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="35">JOHN7956</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="36">JOHN1547</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="37">JOHN6872</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="38">JOHN3487</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="39">JOHN8392</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="40">JOHN3432</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="41">JOHN3412</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="42">JOHN3413</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="43">JOHN3419</div>
    <div class="combi already" data-id="44">JOHN3423</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="45">JOHN3429</div>
    <div class="combi" data-id="46">JOHN3427</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Check the [documentation of `index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) method for more information.

Comment: @ThomasJerichoCapuyan : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the index of element in set of all combi element:

```
var combiDivs = $('#slotMachine2 div.combi');
var firstAlreadyIndex = combiDivs.index(combiDivs.filter(':not(.already)').first());
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgakv3wz/)**

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple `div` without the class `already`.

Your solution has `:first` in it, which will return an array with just 1 object in it. This will log the indices for every element without the class `already`:

```
$('#slotMachine #slotMachine2 div.combi').each(function(index, el) {
    if(!$(el).is('.already')) {
       console.log(index);
    }
});
```